# Multiple arrays inside a struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I know that it is not possible to inline a variable sized array inside a struct because structs must have a fixed size known at compile time. One can, however, have a reference to an array of a size only known at runtime in a struct.

So I have a struct as follows:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public double[,] C;

    internal Foo(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
    {
        this.C = new double[sizeX, sizeY];
    }

    public static Foo Initialize(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
    {
        var foo = new Foo(sizeX, sizeY);

        for (var x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
            {
                foo.C[x, y] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

And I initialize this struct as follows:

```
foo = Foo.Initialize(12, 35);
```

This works well and there are no issues. However, if I try to add additional arrays into the struct as follows:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public double[] eVal;
    public double[,] C;
    public double[,] eVec;

    internal Foo(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
    {
        this.eVal = new double[sizeX];
        this.C = new double[sizeX, sizeY];
        this.eVec = new double[sizeX, sizeY];
    }

    public static Foo Initialize(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
    {
        var foo = new Foo(sizeX, sizeY);

        for (var x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            foo.eVal[x] = 0.0;

            for (var y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
            {
                foo.eVec[x, y] = 0.0;
                foo.C[x, y] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

And I initialize this new struct as follows:

```
foo = Foo.Initialize(12, 35);
```

This does not work properly. It compiles and runs, but when I print out the values of C, there seems to be some sort of a weird memory address issue. In other words, if I run the first struct with only array C in it, the elements of C are calculated correctly. When I run the new struct with the additional arrays, only some of the elements of C are calculated correctly. Others are completely wrong. I have been working on this for some time and cannot seem to figure this out. It seems the new struct does not seem to work properly. Can anyone offer a suggestion on what is going on here and how to fix this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What values are wrong? How are they wrong? The code shown sets things to zero only... What do you see instead of zero? Frankly, I can guarantee here that the issue is your code - the code we can't see

Comment: There is other code that calculates the elements and stores them in C. C is passed by ref to the other methods. The issue is not the other method, I think, because, it works properly when only C is present in the struct.

Comment: @MarcGravel You are likely correct that it may be the other code but why does it work correctly when only C is present in the struct, and doesn't work when  other arrays are present in the struct?

Comment: there is no need for C to be passed by-ref - it is already a reference. It should do no harm either. But: the error is not in the code shown (that assigns zero for no reason - arrays start all-zero), and it has nothing to do with adding fields. If you want us to find it, youlk have to post code that actually shows the problem - ideally runnable.

Comment: @MarcGravel Thank you. I understand re the initialization. I can remove it. I am not sure though why C would automatically be passed by reference to a method? And I still don't understand why a given method would calculate C correctly when only C is present in the struct and not correctly when other arrays are added to the struct. However I will check out the other code as per your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: C isn't automatically passed by reference: the value in C ***is*** a reference. When you pass C around, you are only passing the reference value (essentially the address), not the object. Code can read and write into the array via that. Passing C by-ref is passing a reference to a reference - rarely necessary (the only use case for that would be to allow code to reassign the field to a completely different array)

Comment: @MarcGravel You were absolutely correct. The issue was related to passing C by ref. Once I got rid of passing C and the other arrays by ref, the code works correctly. Thank you for the suggestion.